# Calling the standard approval process from a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object and records of these objects can be submitted for approval via the standard approval process.

I have a custom Visualforce page for overriding the standard view action, so that a user friendly message appears if a particular condition is met.

The Visualforce page is below:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Custom_Object_A__c">
<apex:messages />
    <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Custom_Object_A__c.label} Detail" subtitle="{!Custom_Object_A__c.Name}"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock mode="maindetail" title="{!$ObjectType.Custom_Object_A__c.label} Detail">
        <apex:pageMessage escape="false" detail="Please note: this record <b>must have at least 1 attachment added against it in order to successfully submit it for approval</b>. If you try to submit for approval when there is not at least 1 attachment added, then you will receive an error and will be forced to return to the page." severity="info" strength="3"
        rendered="{!ISBLANK(Custom_Object_A__c.of_Attachments__c) || Custom_Object_A__c.of_Attachments__c < 1}"/>
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Delete" action="{!Delete}"/>


            </apex:pageblockbuttons>


            <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="false" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.Name}"/>
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.Status__c}"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                        <apex:outputlabel value="Owner"/>
                            <apex:outputpanel >
                            <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.OwnerId}"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.of_Attachments__c}"/>
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:pageblocksection title="System Information" showheader="false" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                        <apex:outputlabel value="Created By"/>
                        <apex:outputpanel >
                            <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.CreatedById}"/> 
                            <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.CreatedDate}"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                        <apex:outputlabel value="Last Modified By"/>
                        <apex:outputpanel >
                            <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.LastModifiedById}"/>
                            <apex:outputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.LastModifiedDate}"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>


    <apex:outputpanel >
        <apex:relatedlist list="CombinedAttachments" title="Notes & Attachments"/>
        <apex:relatedlist list="ProcessSteps" title="Approval History"/>
    </apex:outputpanel>

</apex:page>
```

When I select the 'Submit for Approval' button on this page, the below error is returned.

[image]

I looked at this link [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95818/we-need-to-confirm-that-your-request-is-valid-please-repeat-your-last-action), which seems to suggest that:

> "This is an intentional change which has been made by Salesforce in
>   Winter'16 release to remove security vulnerability".

and...

> Staring Winter'16, you will not be able to use the Custom Buttons to
>   call standard URL for Approval Process Submission (which is
>   "/p/process/Submit?... ").

**Questions:**

1. I am unsure why I am receiving these errors, as this is a
   standard button on a Visualforce page?
2. I am unsure what the security vulnerabilities specifically were pre Winter '16 for using Custom Buttons to call standard URL for Approval Process, although I assume it is related to cross-site scripting vulnerability as per
   the Trailhead link [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/secdev_inject_cross_site_scripting)?
3. What are my options to navigate
       around this? I simply want to keep my Visualforce page which
       displays the user friendly message and enables a user to submit for
       approval from the page.

Answer (score 1):

Well I cannot answer all of your questions.
But I can suggest you a solution. We can handle the approval processs in APEX. That is kind of overkill bu writing a controller/extension. But there are ways to do so.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm

Comment: OK - thank you. It's incredibly frustrating to go through all this effort merely to get some helpful messages on the screen.

Comment: I completely understand man :) Hope they fix this in future release :)